# variables transfer in html/javascript programming for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

In traditional web client programming, there are cookie and session for transferring variables.

I wonder that in html/javascript programming for mobile if it is same or transferring varibles using javascript global instance.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use global JavaScript variables, or there is also HTML5 localStorage/sessionStorage/IndexedDB/WebSQL, which is new but usually supported on smartphone browsers.